# Working with JQuery doubleScroll plugin but top scroll bar only shows up after a refresh

Tags: jquery, plugins, scrollbar

I'm currently using the jQuery doubleScroll plugin to display a horizontal scroll bar at the top and bottom of a table with data.
When the window is resized or it is too small to display all the data then the scroll bars show up.
The top scroll bar is not showing up when the page is loaded in, only after I refresh the page it shows up.
There are no issues with the bottom scroll bar.

My assumption is that the table is fetching data from a database while the top scroll bar is being loaded in or something. This is the current jQuery script.

```
(function ($) {

jQuery.fn.doubleScroll = function (userOptions) {

// Default options
var options = {
  contentElement: undefined, // Widest element, if not specified first child element will be used
  scrollCss: {
    'overflow-x': 'auto',
    'overflow-y': 'hidden',
    'height': '20px'
  },
  contentCss: {
    'overflow-x': 'auto',
    'overflow-y': 'hidden'
  },
  onlyIfScroll: true, // top scrollbar is not shown if the bottom one is not present
  resetOnWindowResize: false, // recompute the top ScrollBar requirements when the window is resized
  timeToWaitForResize: 30 // wait for the last update event (usefull when browser fire resize event constantly during ressing)
};

$.extend(true, options, userOptions);

// do not modify
// internal stuff
$.extend(options, {
  topScrollBarMarkup: '<div class="doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper"><div class="doubleScroll-scroll"></div></div>',
  topScrollBarWrapperSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper',
  topScrollBarInnerSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll'
});

var _showScrollBar = function ($self, options) {

  if (options.onlyIfScroll && $self.get(0).scrollWidth <= Math.round($self.width())) {
    // content doesn't scroll
    // remove any existing occurrence...
    $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector).remove();
    return;
  }

  // add div that will act as an upper scroll only if not already added to the DOM
  var $topScrollBar = $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector);

  if ($topScrollBar.length == 0) {

    // creating the scrollbar
    // added before in the DOM
    $topScrollBar = $(options.topScrollBarMarkup);
    $self.before($topScrollBar);

    // apply the css
    $topScrollBar.css(options.scrollCss);
    $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector).css("height", "20px");
    $self.css(options.contentCss);

    var scrolling = false;

    // bind upper scroll to bottom scroll
    $topScrollBar.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', function () {
      if (scrolling) {
        scrolling = false;
        return;
      }
      scrolling = true;
      $self.scrollLeft($topScrollBar.scrollLeft());
    });

    // bind bottom scroll to upper scroll
    var selfScrollHandler = function () {
      if (scrolling) {
        scrolling = false;
        return;
      }
      scrolling = true;
      $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());
    };
    $self.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', selfScrollHandler);
  }

  // find the content element (should be the widest one)    
  var $contentElement;

  if (options.contentElement !== undefined && $self.find(options.contentElement).length !== 0) {
    $contentElement = $self.find(options.contentElement);
  } else {
    $contentElement = $self.find('>:first-child');
  }

  // set the width of the wrappers
  $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector, $topScrollBar).width($contentElement.outerWidth());
  $topScrollBar.width($self.width());
  $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());

}

return this.each(function () {

  var $self = $(this);

  _showScrollBar($self, options);

  // bind the resize handler 
  // do it once
  if (options.resetOnWindowResize) {

    var id;
    var handler = function (e) {
      _showScrollBar($self, options);
    };

    $(window).bind('resize.doubleScroll', function () {
      // adding/removing/replacing the scrollbar might resize the window
      // so the resizing flag will avoid the infinite loop here...
      clearTimeout(id);
      id = setTimeout(handler, options.timeToWaitForResize);
       });

     }

   });

  }

}(jQuery));
```

And this is the script at the bottom of my html page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.table-wrapper').doubleScroll({ resetOnWindowResize: true });
      //some more code
```

Have yet to find a solution, all help would be appreciated.